# Error in element_line(linewidth = 1, colour = "black") : unused argument (linewidth = 1)

Tags: r

using r library SmartEDA
getting this error

```
Error in element_line(linewidth = 1, colour = "black") : 
  unused argument (linewidth = 1)
```

reintall the package but still facing this issue

Comment: As the question is currently written, we cannot really help you. Please provide the code you ran and possibly some example data so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: You need to update ggplot to the latest version (3.4.0) by doing `install.packages("ggplot2")`.  In earlier versions of ggplot, `linewidth` was not used inside `element_line` (it used `size` instead). The `SmartEDA` authors must have updated their code, so now it will only work with the latest version of ggplot2, which you must not have installed yet.

Comment: I'm not the original question owner, but I had this problem with the `jtools` package and @AllanCameron 's solution to update `ggplot2` fixed the issue.